# Using Google Sheets, how do I transpose data from one column into multiple rows based on conditions

Tags: google-sheets, transpose

Tab 1 looks like this:
|ID|CODE|VALUE
|------|---|----
|100010|309|34
|100010|312|34
|100010|392|17
|100010|394|0.31
|100020|309|34
|100020|312|62
|100020|392|0.25
|100020|400|23

Tab 2 looks like
|ID|309|312|392|394|401|404|
|------|---|---|---|---|---|---|
|100010|
|100020|

I want to transpose the values from Tab 1 into Tab 2, by appropriate code and ID. Also note that occasionally individual IDs will use different sets of codes, though largely the same (see 10010 code 394 vs 100020 code 400 - these are the 5th and 9th rows of Tab 1).

I've tried a bunch of different methods like QUERY, FILTER, ARRAY, TRANSPOSE, but I can't quite get the right syntax.

One of my rudimentary attempts:
=QUERY(tab1!B:B,"select * where A contains '"& 1W &"',TRANSPOSE(tab1!D:D)) and A is not null", 0)

Thanks for you help!

Edit: I added a screen cap of the tables just incase the markdown isn't showing correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68pIk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(Tab1!A:C,"select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B",1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your posted data is in a sheet called `Sheet1`, and that your data runs A:C (with headers in A1:C1). Also suppose that the first ID in your results sheet is in cell A2.

In cell B2, place the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"~"&FILTER(B1:1,B1:1<>""),{Sheet8!A:A&"~"&Sheet8!B:B,Sheet8!C:C},2,FALSE)))`

This formula assumes that you are wanting to manually enter the IDs and Codes to the left and across the top in the results sheet (an assumption made on the fact that you have Codes 401 and 404 listed in the results sheet yet not in the raw-data sheet).

The formula will continue to accommodate new IDs and Codes added to the left and across the top without any modifications to the formula.

Given you posted example data, the raw-data entry for ID 100020 with Code 400 will not be found in your results sheet, since the value 400 is not present in Row 1 of the results sheet. Likewise, in your results sheet, there would be no returns for Codes 401 or 404, since they don't currently exist in your raw-data sheet.